# How execute 3 function on 4 threads using Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have 3 function and want execute each on new thread using Python

Each function just a math operations.

I need to start each function in each core of process. In Java it's look like:

```
Thread threadF1 = new Thread(f1);
Thread threadF2 = new Thread(f2);
Thread threadF3 = new Thread (f3);

threadF1.start();
threadF2.start();
threadF3.start();
```

And if i have 4 cores my program uses 75% of CPU.

I wrote this in Python:

```
 thread = Thread(target = F1, args=(N,))
 thread.start()

 thread2 = Thread(target = F2, args=(N,))
 thread2.start()

 thread3 = Thread(target = F3, args=(N,))
 thread3.start()
```

but it uses just 25%. How force working code in Python using 3/4 cores?

Comment: Note this question: [what is global interpreter lock - GIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much python, but try `thread.start_new_thread(F1, (N))` for each of your functions.

Here is some documentation I found on the method: [thread.start_new_thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread)

---

EDIT:

turns out `thread` was renamed `_thread` in python 3:

```
import _thread
_thread.start_new_thread(F1, (N,))
```

Comment: I wrote `my_thread = threading.Thread(target=F1(N))  my_thread.setDaemon(True)    my_thread.start()`  but each function doesn't starting in same time

Comment: @A.N.R.I, please edit the question and add that information to the question, where it can be formatted readably.  Also explain  “doesn't starting in same time” -- do you mean it looks like the threads aren't running concurrently?  Do you mean they didn't start at the same nanosecond?  Or what?  Please reply by editing question

Answer (score 0):

In CPython, it is hard to achieve parallelism through threading. This has to do with the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock).

One way to work around that is to use the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.